# Remove all files, except for two

Tags: bash, wildcards

I would like to delete everything in one folder, with the exception of two files:

```
exec.js
.git
```

I found this:

```
rm !(exec.js|.git)
```

Which works in the CL, but when I try to store in a sh file, and call with `bash file.sh`, this happens:

```
test.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
test.sh: line 1: `rm !(exec.js|.git)'
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: Can you please explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: "I would like to delete everything in one folder, with the exception of two files"

Comment: On Ubuntu, `sh` is a symlink to dash - are you sure you are executing the script with bash? How exactly are you running it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need

```
shopt -s extglob
```

inside the script.

Your bash configuration presumably turns this on automatically for interactive shells (perhaps because you load the bash-completion package for context-sensitive completion); you need to turn it on manually inside scripts.

Also make sure that your script starts with `#!/bin/bash` (or a variant like `#!/usr/bin/env bash`, otherwise it may be executed by a different shell that doesn't support this syntax.

For example, this script will create a few files and then remove all except the two you want to keep:

```
$ cat x
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

touch f1 f2 f3 exec.js .git foo bar

echo Before: $(ls -A)

rm !(exec.js|.git)

echo After: $(ls -A)
```

In execution:

```
$ bash x
Before: .git bar exec.js f1 f2 f3 foo x
rm: cannot remove '.': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '..': Is a directory
After: .git exec.js
```

Note that you get errors with `.` and `..`; you'll have seen those on the command line as well:

```
$ touch f1 f2 f3 exec.js .git foo bar

$ rm !(exec.js|.git)
rm: cannot remove '.': Is a directory
rm: cannot remove '..': Is a directory
```

Comment: `bash` doesn't turn it on automatically. It's bash-completion, if you have it installed, that does.

Comment: Can you provide an working example?

Comment: I'm trying to: ```shopt -s extglob
rm !(1.js|test.sh)```... Doesn't work, the same problem happens.

Comment: Example provided.

Answer (score 2):

As a suggestion, you can add

```
GLOBIGNORE=.:..
```

after the `shopt -s extglob` to avoid the `rm: cannot remove '.': Is a directory` error.